# Search Bar in HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, searchbar

I created an HTML table with a lot of information about a country. Now I want the user to be able to search in this table for a piece of information like the Area.

```js
function selectRow() {
  var input, filter, table, trs, td;
  input = document.getElementById("search");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("dataRows");
  trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (let index = 0; index < trs.length; index++) {
    td = trs[index].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      trs[index].display = "";
    } else {
      trs[index].display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="selectRow()" placeholder="Search.." />

<table id="dataRows">
  <tr>
    <th>Attributes</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Australia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Area</td>
    <td>7,741,220.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Population</td>
    <td>25,466,459</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But when I try to use it I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined"
I can't figure out why the td is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most helpful thing to demonstrate first, I think, is a method that will let you diagnose this yourself in future. This sort of difficulty **will** occur all the time, so here is one method to help you generally problem solve these types of issues.

You know that `<td>` is not the value you expect, so check your expectation by outputting the values that you use to acquire `<td>`. You can do that by adding these console.log lines at the top of your loop:

```
for (let index = 0; index < trs.length; index++) {
  console.log("trs[index]",trs[index]);
  console.log("trs[index].getElementsByTagName(td)", trs[index].getElementsByTagName("td"));
```

With that, you should see that the first `<tr>` has `<th>` elements, not `<td>`! These surprises happen all the time, it's great to learn tricks to check your assumptions the quickest way you can.

Here's a very simple solution, the first and last line of this block are the same in your code:

```
for (let index = 0; index < trs.length; index++) {
    var tds = trs[index].getElementsByTagName("td");
    if(tds.length == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    td = tds[0];
    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
```

Looks like you've just started working through building this, I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

use ur code like this to get best result and without any error

edit

I think the tricky part of this is actually the accepting of user input intelligently. Therefore, I'd say the best thing to do is to pass off your searching to an autocomplete-type plugin. Once the page is ready, you pass the focus to an input text box, and then let the plugin do its magic as you search...

For example, you could use the quicksearch plugin.

Then given a table of data and an input like this:

```html
<input id="searcher" type="text" name="searcher">
```

You could have a ready function that looks like this:

```js
$('#searcher').quicksearch('table tbody tr', {
    'delay': 100,
    'bind': 'keyup keydown',
    'show': function() {
        if ($('#searcher').val() === '') {
            return;
        }
        $(this).addClass('show');
    },
    'onAfter': function() {
        if ($('#searcher').val() === '') {
            return;
        }
        if ($('.show:first').length > 0){
            $('html,body').scrollTop($('.show:first').offset().top);
        }
    },
    'hide': function() {
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    },
    'prepareQuery': function(val) {
        return new RegExp(val, "i");
    },
    'testQuery': function(query, txt, _row) {
        return query.test(txt);
    }
});

$('#searcher').focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLhAd/369/

Comment: But I want to use it in a table for a better overview, is this also possible?

Comment: it is possible let me upload a code exaple for u wait few minutes